# Android:How to close dialog after activity destroy?

Tags: android

For example, my app have activityA and activityB, activityC, activityA is the mainactivity:

My app has file import feature, so I can import file into my app from sdcard, if you

import file, will open activityC, and you can see the import file in activityC, configure

code:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityA">

     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" /> 
            <data ...../>
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Step: Open activityB and pop a dialog ---> Press device home bottom out the app ---> Open file manager app and tap a support file, select myself app in the support list dialog ---->
app will open, then I can see ActivityC show the import file, but can also see the dialog which pop in activityB.

I want to close the dialog when import file, what can i do?

Comment: When you press home button your current activity is paused and you navigate to home screen. When you return your activity resumes. I am confused regarding the steps mentioned above. Its not clear to me

Comment: what context do you use for the dialog

Comment: Put simply, If i improt file, When return, the activityB will destory, and the activityA will create, then i can see the dialog(which poped by activityB) display above activityA. This is not my want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the dialog box when you press home button. You can close your dialog box by calling `dialog.cancel()`. When you press `home button` the activity moves into the pause state, so you can cancel the dialog box in `onPause() function`.

Check whether the dialog is showing when the app in pause state use this code for that

```
//in on pause()
 if(dialog.isShowing()){ 
  boolean dialogCanceld=true;
  dialog.cancel();
 }
 //in onResume
  if(dialagCanceld){
     //show your dialog
  }
```

Comment: If i can't import file, for example, i return by long press home button, the activityB and dialog will display normally. In this way, cancel the dialog box in onPause() function, and if i can't import file, i can show the dialog box in onResume() function?